# Segmentation fault thread (monitor)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define N_ASS 4

pthread_t tid[N_ASS];
//mutex
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

//variabili condition
pthread_cond_t c_ass[N_ASS], c_pass[N_PASS];



void * checkDoc ()
{
 printf("do stuff\n");
}


int main()
{

 int err;
 int i = 0;

 for(i;i<N_ASS;i++){
    err = pthread_create (&tid[i], NULL, checkDoc(), NULL);
    pthread_cond_wait(&c_ass[i],&mutex);
    }

 for(i=0;i<N_ASS;i++)
    pthread_cond_signal(&c_ass[i]);

 for(i=0;i<N_ASS;i++) {
     err = pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
     printf("%d joined\n",i);
 }

 printf("End\n");

}
```

I just want to say that I'm a little noob who is just learning and this is my first question, if I have to do something else just tell me and I'll do it!
So this is the code, I got one first problem, it makes segmentation-fault and I don't know why.
The output is:

do stuff //1,2,3 or 4 time

Segmentation fault

Nothing else, i runned at least 20 time.

Comment: Run it with your debugger who will tell you where the segault occurs.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but `int  i = 0; for( i; i < N_ASS; i++)` is awkward and unusual, you should write `int  i ; for( i = 0; i < N_ASS; i++)` .

Comment: You're also not initializing your mutex nor your condition variables.

Answer (score 5):

You should be getting compiler warnings here, as the thread function (or rather what is *supposed* to be the thread function) doesn't return anything.

This will lead to *undefined behavior* because you don't pass a pointer to the `checkDoc` function to `pthread_create`, you actually *call* the `checkDoc` function, and use the returned pointer as the pointer to the thread function. As the `checkDoc` function doesn't actually return anything you will have undefined behavior, and most likely a crash.

Simple solution? Don't *call* the `checkDoc` function:

```
pthread_create (&tid[i], NULL, checkDoc, NULL)
//                             ^^^^^^^^
//       No longer calling the function
```

And if you state that a function returns a value, you should actually do it. If the returned value is not used then just return `NULL`.

---

Also, in C when you declare a function without any formal arguments, it's the same thing as saying that the function accepts any number of arguments of any type. POSIX thread functions must specifically accept a `void *` argument. If you do not use the argument in the thread function, then simply don't name the argument:

```
void * checkDoc (void *) { ... }
```

This last bit also has implications for the `main` function, as the C specification explicitly says that the `main` function should either take two arguments (an `int` and an `char *[]`), or be `void`. If you have a function which doesn't take any arguments you *must* explicitly say that by using `void` as argument.

---

There are also other issues with your code. Like you not initializing the structures you use properly. Or like you waiting for the condition variable right after creating the each thread, and as you don't signal the condition variable until *after* you start waiting for it then you will wait forever and the code will not continue to the part where you actually call the signalling function.

Comment: He *should* be getting an error, but sadly, GCC's defaults do not report problems such as these. It's why I always ***strongly*** recommend compiling with `-Wall`.

Comment: This is just a little part of a bigger program, so I need checkDoc but if I write:
` void * checkDoc(void *){ ... } `
it makes the error: parameter name omitted, too few arguments to function

Comment: @Bobbio Even a complete newbie should be able to figure out how to fix that error.

Comment: @TimČas I personally have a few more warning flags (which depends on language) but it's always a good idea to enable more warnings, and actually try to understand what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Well, I feel `-Wextra` is overzealous (at least for C). I think `-Wall` is just right. For example, `-Wextra` warns about unused arguments --- and unlike in C++, you can't just omit the name of the argument in definitions, e.g. `int foo(int a, int, int c) { ... }`, only in declarations. That means that for some functions, you are *always* going to have an unused argument (e.g. unused `userdata` arguments for callbacks).